# Firebase Dynamic Links - UTM params not accessible within AppDelegate from long link

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, utm

I'm implementing Firebase Dynamic Links and all seems to be working, except that when I use the long dynamic link rather than a short link, the UTM params show as empty.

For example, I have a short link as follows:

`https://example.page.link/spectest`

With the corresponding long link:

`https://example.page.link/?link=https://www.example.com/products/test_product1554395&isi=966121224&ibi=com.example.example-uk-dev&utm_campaign=My+Sale&utm_medium=clc&utm_source=Test_Store`

In the app delegate I have the following:

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
            Adjust.appWillOpen(userActivity.webpageURL!)
        }
        let canContinue = ActivityManager.application(application, continue: userActivity)

        if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
            let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { dynamicLink, error in
                guard error == nil else {
                    return
                }

                if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                    self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
                    print("*** UTMs: \(dynamicLink.utmParametersDictionary)")
                }
            }

            if linkHandled {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }

        return canContinue
    }
```

When I access the short link, I get the following in the console:

`*** UTMs: ["utm_source": Test_Store, "utm_campaign": My Sale, "utm_medium": clc]`

But when I use the long link the params dictionary is empty:

`*** UTMs: [:]`

In both of the above, the events are correctly logged in Firebase and google analytics, including the campaign name etc. So why are the UTMs not accessible when I access the content via the long link?